# How to use QuickFIX in QtCreator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, quickfix

What modifications are required  to build QuickFix(FIX Engine) in Qt Creator?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** After you compile your QuickFIX library, include the QuickFIX library and add these params to your project's .pro file:

```
LIBS += \
-fexceptions \
-lpthread \
-lxml2 \
-lz
```

I still haven't figured out how to get everything in Qt Creator and then compile the library.